# Flutter: no connected devices

Tags: android-virtual-device, flutter

I'm developing flutter project and I'm a newbie to flutter, My Avd manager shows only virtual device except real, whereas my another android project shows my real device and my [Android WIFI ADB Here is Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/us4fJ.png) is also showing a connected device, but flutter device selection showing nothing, What should I do? I'm following these [steps](https://flutter.io/get-started/test-drive/) but nothing is happening. I'm opening Emulator from AVD manager but whenever I run the project it does not show any device, [Here is another image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rogP0.png).

When I choose MainActivity to run than Android Studio shows device but it shows error like

> Cannot start compilation: the output path is not specified for module "flutter_app1_android".
>   Specify the output path in Configure Project.

I solved the problem then another problem occur

> Unable to determine application id: com.android.tools.idea.run.ApkProvisionException: ERROR: APK path is not specified for module "flutter_app2_android"
>   Client not ready yet.

I searched it for this problem but unable to set path because of Project Structure Does not show Module tool, It is showing only SDK Location and project, [Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jwrsi.png)

Comment: When you run `flutter devices` what comes up?

Comment: @Colin I attached Image, it is showing no device whereas android project shows devices.

Comment: @Colin see my edited Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I found the solution, It was showing no device because of my flutter SDK was not installed properly. I uninstalled the Flutter Sdk. And follow other processes to install the Flutter

1) Go to the Git Bash and run the Command

```
git clone -b beta https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
```

it will download SDK at default place.

2) Now run the Command

```
flutter doctor
```

whenever you run the command it will show some error it may be SDK location not found and device not found.

[image]

set The Home Variable,

1) Go to Control Panel

2) Go to User Account

3)Change My Environment Variable (If your SDK is somewhere else then set Location like)

[image]

and restart your system to make changes and again run the command

```
flutter doctor
```

your project will show device and emulator which you are using.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. **Make sure  USB debugging on your phone is ON** (you can turn it on in Settings -> Developer Options ->Usb Debugging)
2. Connect your phone to your PC
3. You can download ADB Driver Installer 2.0, extract it, click the **ADBDriverInstaller.exe** and just click INSTALL then.

[image: ADB]

Hope this will help