# Unable to run Flutter Plugin in Android Studio

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a Flutter Plugin following this: https://flutter.io/developing-packages/#step-1-create-the-package

```
flutter create --template=plugin -i swift hello
```

```
flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.9.4, on Mac OS X 10.14 18A391, locale en-DK)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.2)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[✓] VS Code (version 1.28.2)
[✓] Connected devices (1 available)
```

Update: I have added the plugins Dart and Flutter to Android Studio(now Flutter doctor is all checkmarks), but still no run button. Note that this is a plugin generated. I am able to create a new Flutter project, but for this I dont know how to run the example apps?

I can run the example code with `flutter run` but opening the project in Android Studio do not show any run button?

Comment: Your output says you don't have the Flutter or Dart plugins installed for Android Studio. Are you sure you've installed these plugins?

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49082240/cannot-start-compilation-the-output-path-is-not-specified-for-module-flutter-a) you may find your solution and open all images i think you would find your solution too.

Comment: Right thanks, how do I install the plugins?

Comment: Ahh ok, I am an iOS dev. and I should have read: https://flutter.io/get-started/editor/#androidstudio

Comment: Sorry, I will delete this again

Comment: Open plugin preferences (Preferences>Plugins on macOS, File>Settings>Plugins on Windows & Linux).

Comment: Same problem, note this is a generated project: lutter create --template=plugin -i swift hello