# android studio emulator not selectable

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I want to start coding with flutter, so i decided to download android studio.I created an avd called "Pixel 2 API 28" with android pie. When i want to select the pixel 2 as the avd device, the programme tells me that theres no avd, but on the right i can see the avd i created. When i put my cursor on it, it says "not applicable for the main.dart configuration". i have HAXM installed and Hyper-V is disabled, but i also tried it with both being active. I used the default code, which appears when you launch android studio.
Please help!!!

Edit: 
I somehow managed to select it now, but i get this error: Running multiple emulators with the same AVD is an experimental feature. Please use -read-only flag to enable this feature.

[image] 
[image]

Comment: I was able to do it by opening a native android project and setup an AVD. After that the device started appearing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: no connected devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49082240/flutter-no-connected-devices)

Comment: @RahulRaj nope, already did that

Comment: @MichaelHathi when i open a native project, i can only choose between Kotlin and Java as programming languages, but not flutter

Comment: All I'm saying is to setup your AVD in your android project and then return to flutter project.

Answer (score 2):

Try starting the emulator from avd and then check if the device is showing up there if not try running

```sh
flutter devices
```

If the device shows there you can try running

```sh
flutter run -d <your-device-name>
```

You can also check whether the android sdk is configured with flutter try running

```sh
flutter config --android-sdk /path/andriod/sdk
```

hope it helps

Comment: starting it manually works, but i still cannot use it to run my programme

Comment: Start manually the emulator. After, to run your app manually go to the root folder of your project and type "flutter run" command. It will build your project and install your app. You can do hot reload manually typing "r" in che console terminal

Answer (score 0):

Close **Android Studio** and Run again as **Administrator**
This is Only the solution i got after working hard for 3 days.